# Contador em python

Tags: python, python-2.7, for, contador, range

Bom eu estou fazendo um programa de screenshot mas quero que ele substitua no nome do arquivo ao salvar, os caracteres "XX", pelo número do print.
Ex: ScreenShotXX.jpg
no "XX" quero colocar o numero da print
ex: 01, 02
Codigo usado:

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

def main():
    image = ImageGrab.grab()

    cont = 1

    for c in cont:

        c =+ 1

        image.save('screenShot' + str(c) + '.jpg', 'jpeg')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Estou usando o **python 2.7**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve apenas acessar a pasta onde as Screenshots estão sendo salvas, verificar se há arquivos na mesma, se sim, pega o ultimo arquivo após fazer o ordenamento, e extrair o XX do nome dessa ultima foto, basta somar +1 e salvar a nova captura, mas se a pasta estiver vazia, apenas considere o valor 01, pois ela séria a primeira captura.

Answer (score 4):

O seu código não está muito claro. Você define uma variável `cont` com o valor `1` e depois usa uma variável `c` em um laço (sem usar o `range`), mas incrementa ela dentro do laço.....?

Se você sabe o número de capturas que quer, coloque esse número dentro da variável `cont` e faça assim:

```
cont = 10

for c in range(cont):

    file = 'screenShot{:05d}.jpg'.format(c)

    print(file)
```

Resultado (veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/3qTHnP)):

```
screenShot00000.jpg
screenShot00001.jpg
screenShot00002.jpg
screenShot00003.jpg
screenShot00004.jpg
screenShot00005.jpg
screenShot00006.jpg
screenShot00007.jpg
screenShot00008.jpg
screenShot00009.jpg
```

A máscara `05d` usada na chamada de `format` diz que o número é inteiro (`d`), com tamanho de 5 caracteres com 0 à esquerda (`05` - se usar só `5` haverá espaços à esquerda).

Ou seja, o seu código final pode ficar assim:

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

def main():
    cont = 10 # Número de capturas

    for c in range(cont):

        # Desnecessário
        # c =+ 1 

        image = ImageGrab.grab()
        image.save('screenShot{:05d}.jpg'.format(c), 'jpeg')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: A sua resposta está extensa, mas você não uma das confusões do AP que eu percebi aqui (achoq ue num golpe de intuição): Acho que ele pretende grvar uma sequência de screenshots, - não faz sentido?  Nesse caso, seria só passar a chamada a `ImageGrab.grab` para dentro do loop, e inserir uma pausa, com  `time.sleep`  mesmo.   Você pode colocar mais um exemplo assim?

Comment: @jsbueno Você tem razão, faz mais sentido o `grab` dentro do laço. Vou alterar, obrigado pelo aviso! :) Faz sentido também a pausa, mas como nenhum de nós tem certeza absoluta do que o AP realmente quer, deixo isso a cargo dele. P.S.: Você achou mesmo minha resposta extensa? rs

Comment: Realmente há coisas que não percebo ... Esta resposta está muito melhor comparada à outra